# Finding $E[X]$ with the Law of total expectation

Tags: statistics, expected-value

**Question:** Prisoner locked in a cell with $n$ doors. Only one door leads to freedom, and all the other doors lead to a dungeon where the prisoner is forced to stay $a_{i} $ days for $i=2,....n$ when $i$ is the selected door (the first door can be set as the door that leads to freedom, so that $a_{1}=0$). The prisoner chooses a random door with equal probability to all doors and passes through it. If he did not choose the door that leads to freedom, after staying in the dungeon $i$ (when $i \neq 1$) he returns to the cell and picks again a random door. Suppose the prisoner remembers which doors he has already checked. Let $X$ be the number of days till the prisoner gets to freedom. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

**My attempt to solve:**
Let be $Y$ be the indictor for the door that was open so:
 $$
E[X|Y=i]=\begin{cases}
 0& \ i=1 \\ 
 E[X]+ a_{i}&  i=2,3.....,n 
\end{cases}
$$
I used the Law of total expectation and got:

$$
E[X]=E[E[X|Y=i]]=\sum_{i=2}^{n}E[X|Y=i]\cdot P(Y=i)
$$
$$
E[X]=\sum_{i=2}^{n}(E[X|]+ a_{i})\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-k}
$$
$$
E[X]=\sum_{i=2}^{n} (a_{i})\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\frac{1}{n-k})+ (n-1)E[X]
$$

This answer is wrong.

The right answer is:
$
E[X]=\sum_{i=2}^{n} \left(\frac{a_{i}}{n}\right)\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k-1}{n-1}\right)
$

But I can’t understand how they can to this expression.

Comment: When you write $E[X | Y = i] = a_i + E[X]$ for $i=2, ..., n$, you are implying the prisoner forgets which door he already checked so this is not right.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for explaining me where was my mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is just $\frac 12\times \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$.

Each losing door has a $\frac 12$ chance of being selected prior to the winning door, so each of the losing doors contributes half of its days to the expected number of days.

Note:  The official answer simplifies to this since $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {k-1}{n-1}=\frac 1{n-1}\times \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k=\frac 1{n-1}\times \frac {n(n-1)}2=\frac n2$$

thus $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {a_i}n\times \sum_{k=1}^n\frac {k-1}{n-1}=\frac 1n\times \sum_{i=1}^na_i\times \frac n2=\frac 12\times \sum_{i=1}^na_i$$

To be clear:  since $a_1=0$ there is no difference between $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ and $\sum_{i=2}^na_i$.

Comment: Wow thank you very much, this is a very beautiful solution. I wouldn’t think about it. Just one question: can you please explain how you knew that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$?

Comment: Standard computation, see the [Triangular Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Got that, thank you very much for all of your help :)

Comment: Sorry I'm bothering you again, but I have one more question. How can we say that the probability to pick a losing door is $0.5$ and picking a winning door is also a $0.5$ if we have $n-1$ losing doors and $1$ winning door?

Comment: I didn't say that.  I said that if you fix a particular losing door, the probability of opening that door prior to the winning door is $\frac 12$.  Think of it this way:  before starting all this, the prisoner chooses the order in which he will open the doors.  That means he chooses a random permutation of $1, \cdots, n$.  In such a random permutation, the chances that $i$ precedes $j$, for $i\neq j$ is $\frac 12$ by symmetry.

Comment: So can we say that the prisoner kind of sorting the losing doors into a line, so that every time he chooses the losing door he has to options before him: the next losing door in the line and the winning door?

Comment: I don't understand.  Keep it simple.  Say there were $n=3$ doors.  Then the prisoner chooses one of the six permutations $(1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2, 1,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2), (3, 2,1)$.   Say the winning door is $\#2$.  Then we see that door $1$ comes before door $2$ in exactly half the permutations.

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me a lot.